# Setting datetime inside QDateTimeEdit widget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I have to set the date and time available as a string in the following format.
"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S"

```
cur_time = strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime())
cur_date = DATA[1]
date_time = cur_date+" "+cur_time
now = QtCore.QDate.fromString(date_time, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
self.dateTimeEdit.setDate(now)
```

But this is not working.

Comment: what is `DATA[1]`?

Answer (score 1):

The format of `date` and `datetime` is different from the format of `QDate` and `QDateTime`, you should not use% in the Qt format, check the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromString-1) for more detail:

Assuming `DATA[1]` has a format `%Y/%m/%d` as you try to use, you can use the following code:

```
cur_time = strftime("%H:%M:%S", gmtime())
cur_date = "2018/11/10"
date_time = cur_date+" "+cur_time
now = QtCore.QDateTime.fromString(date_time, 'yyyy/M/d hh:mm:ss')
self.dateTimeEdit.setDateTime(now)
```